# Insert a cell location in condition formatting

Tags: excel, vba

so I have a code like this:

```
Sub ApplyIconSets()

Dim rng As Range
Dim iset As IconSetCondition

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtained Range Object", Type:=8)
rng.Name = "selected"

LastRow = Range("selected").Rows.Count
LastColumn = Range("selected").Columns.Count

With Range("selected")
    For i = 2 To LastColumn
        For r = 1 To LastRow
            Set iset = .Cells(r, i).FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
            With iset
                .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Arrows)
                .ReverseOrder = False
                .ShowIconOnly = False
            End With
            With iset.IconCriteria(2)
                .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
                .Value = Range("selected").Cells(r, i).Offset(, -1)
            End With
            With iset.IconCriteria(3)
                .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
                .Value = Range("selected").Cells(r, i).Offset(, -1)
            End With
        Next r
    Next i
End With
```

End Sub

So basically this code applies IconSet condition formatting to a cell based on its preceding cell value. The code works perfectly fine, however there's one point I want to improve it.

When I check the condition applied, the code inputs the preceding cell absolute value instead of the cell's location. 
[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j31tJ.png)

However, I want the code to input the cell location, so that when I change the data, it still works instead of having me rerun the code. 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sRIt.png)

I have tried to change

```
.Value = Range("selected").Cells(r,i).Offset(,-1).Address
```

But it returns a string, hence the condition won't work.

Anyone knows a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you've got your conditional format logic right. Your code as it stands will never show an amber arrow because `IconCriteria(3)` will evaluate first. Since `IconCriteria(2)` has identical property values, it will never be met. If you wanted the green arrow to display for numbers greater than the tested cell value and the amber arrow to display for numbers equal to the value, then you'd need to write the code as given below.

I'm also wondering if a `ForEach` loop might be simpler, especially as it would pass the cell range itself so you could just derive your workbook and worksheet objects from that. This would avoid a potential problems of your unqualified ranges. You'd simply need to add an `If` statement to ensure that you didn't try to offset past column 1.

All in all, then, the code below might serve your purposes. BTW I'd recommend adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and handling the case where the user hits Cancel on the input box:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyIconSets()

    Dim sel As Range, cell As Range

    ' Acquire the target range and handle a cancelled input box.
    On Error GoTo Canx
    Set sel = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtained Range Object", Type:=8)

    ' Iterate cell by cell to add the condition.
    On Error GoTo EH
    For Each cell In sel.Cells

        'Ignore the cell if it is in column 1.
        If cell.Column > 1 Then

            With cell.FormatConditions
                'Delete existing conditions.
                .Delete
                'Add a new condition.
                With .AddIconSetCondition
                    .IconSet = cell.Worksheet.Parent.IconSets(xl3Arrows)
                    'Set the amber criterion.
                    'Note: we have to use '>=' but anything '>' will be caught
                    'in the green operator, so only '=' will meet this criterion.
                    With .IconCriteria(2)
                        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                        .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
                        .Value = "=" & cell.Worksheet.Name & "!" & cell.Offset(, -1).Address
                    End With
                    'Set the green criterion.
                    'Note: we have to use just '>' because this is evaluated first
                    'and '>=' would result in amber never capturing a value.
                    With .IconCriteria(3)
                        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                        .Operator = xlGreater
                        .Value = "=" & cell.Worksheet.Name & "!" & cell.Offset(, -1).Address
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub

Canx:
    Debug.Print "User cancelled."
    Exit Sub
EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want.

```
Sub ApplyIconSets()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim iSet As IconSetCondition
    Dim i As Integer, R As Integer

    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtained Range Object", Type:=8)
    Rng.Name = "selected"

    LastRow = Range("selected").Rows.Count
    LastColumn = Range("selected").Columns.Count

    With Range("selected")
        For i = 1 To LastColumn
            For R = 1 To LastRow
                Set iSet = .Cells(R, i).FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
                With iSet
                    .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Arrows)
                    .ReverseOrder = False
                    .ShowIconOnly = False
                End With
                With iSet.IconCriteria(2)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
                    .Value = "=" & Range("selected").Cells(R, i).Offset(, -1).Address
                End With
                With iSet.IconCriteria(3)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
                    .Value = "=" & Range("selected").Cells(R, i).Offset(, -1).Address
                End With
            Next R
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I didn't want to spend the time experimenting further: I think that the condition can be set for the entire range in one go, causing Excel to set relative formatting instead of absolute. You may like to try that. There would be a difference in speed. You may also like to add code which deletes existing CF before applying the new. CF gets overloaded easily and will then slow down your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to define in each segment, the value as a reference to the cell like this:

```
With iset.IconCriteria(3)
   .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
   .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
   .Value = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
End With
```

You'd have to replace the string with variables to something like this:

```
.Value = "=Sheet1!" & Range("selected").Cells(r, i).Offset(, -1).Address
```

Comment: I can't use an absolute reference since each cell will have different values. I tried to add "=Sheet1!" but it returns with an Object error (noted sheet1 is actually my sheet name as well)